# Pylint - Ignore errors from a designated package

Tags: python, pylint

Due to how a package I am using works, any use of a function from it causes pylint to declare there is an no such function and stop execution ([Github issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1945)), which is making it impossible to work with. The package is functional, just in a way that causes pylint to throw a false positive. How do I tell pylint to ignore a package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some modules and packages cannot be understood by the pylint inference mechanism.  Add a line to the pylint configuration file `ignored-modules=x, y, z` that tells Pylint to stop checking for missing members from modules x, y and z.  See the comments in the default configuration file.

Comment: I don't see anything in the comments concerning this setting, and trying to put it in my user settings as is or as a string causes errors.

Comment: Look in the [TYPECHECK] section of the pylint resource configuration (rc) file.